# Connection Failed at Email Client

Tags: java, email, client, jakarta-mail

I've got some error for connection email server. I think the problem is in connection, because always failed for downloading message from server.

Part of my code :

```
// Connect to e-mail server.
public void connect() {
    // Display connect dialog.
    ConnectDialog dialog = new ConnectDialog(this);
    dialog.show();

    // Build connection URL from connect dialog settings.
    StringBuffer connectionUrl = new StringBuffer();
    connectionUrl.append(dialog.getTypes() + "://");
    connectionUrl.append(dialog.getUsername() + ":");
    connectionUrl.append(dialog.getPassword() + "@");
    connectionUrl.append(dialog.getServer() + "/");

/* Display dialog stating that messages are
   currently being downloaded from server. */
    final DownloadingDialog downloadingDialog =
            new DownloadingDialog(this);
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            downloadingDialog.show();
        }
    });

    // Establish JavaMail session and connect to server.
    Store store = null;
    try {
        // Initialize JavaMail session with SMTP server.
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", dialog.getSmtpServer());
        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        // Connect to e-mail server.
        URLName urln = new URLName(connectionUrl.toString());
        store = session.getStore(urln);
        store.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Close the downloading dialog.
        downloadingDialog.dispose();

        // Show error dialog.
        showError("Unable to connect.", true);
    }

    // Download message headers from server.
    try {
        // Open main "INBOX" folder.
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        // Get folder's list of messages.
        Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

        // Retrieve message headers for each message in folder.
        FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();

        profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
        folder.fetch(messages, profile);

        // Put messages in table.
        tableModel.setMessages(messages);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Close the downloading dialog.
        downloadingDialog.dispose();

        // Show error dialog.
        showError("Unable to download messages.", true);
    }

    // Close the downloading dialog.
    downloadingDialog.dispose();
}

// Show error dialog and exit afterwards if necessary.
private void showError(String message, boolean exit) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, message, "Error",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    if (exit)
        System.exit(0);
}

// Get a message's content.
public static String getMessageContent(Message message)
throws Exception {
    Object content = message.getContent();
    if (content instanceof Multipart) {
        StringBuffer messageContent = new StringBuffer();
        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) content;
        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
            Part part = (Part) multipart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (part.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                messageContent.append(part.getContent().toString());
            }
        }
        return messageContent.toString();
    } else {
        return content.toString();
    }
}

// Run the E-mail Client.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EmailClient2 client = new EmailClient2();
    client.show();

    // Display connect dialog.
    client.connect();
}
```

}

When i run my application :

server:pop.gmail.com
username:********@gmail.com
password:*************
smtp server:smtp.gmail.com

and my error message "Unable to connect"

Comment: In your `catch` blocks it would be better to actually print the `exceptions` so that you can see what is going wrong

Comment: @ScaryWombat I guess you're right, but there's no wrong in my code and not showing the exception. Because only the connection that failed. Or from my internet connection?

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).